# Identify Entity Framework, linq to sql, linq to entities, DbContext or ObjectContext

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am confused over several data mappers Microsoft has developed.

I want to know how can we identify quickly which mapper is used in the DAL.

I guess, if `.dbml` file it is Linq-to-SQL & `.edmx` file it will be Entity Framework.

Can somebody advise how can we correctly identify which mapper is used???

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its correct that when you have a .dbml file the project is using linq to sql, and .edmx stands for entity framework.

Linq to entities is not another orm its just how the linq query is called when working with entity framewok, since the classes that the entity framework generates are called "entities", its just a naming convention to state the difference like

- Linq to Sql (only this share the same name for the mapper and the Linq naming convention)
- Linq to Entities
- Linq to XML
- Linq to Objects
- Linq to Sharepoint
- Linq to DataSet

If you want to figure out if you are using the DbContext or ObjectContext API in the Entity Framework you have to find the context class, which does the whole work and look with what its inherited.

```
public class Entities : DbContext
```

or

```
public class Entities : ObjectContext
```

You can also figure it out if you see t4 templates under the .edmx root in the Solution Explorer, they are called "ModelName".tt and "ModelName".Context.tt, if those files are present you are using the DbContext API if not than ObjectContext.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right..
if .dbml file it is linq to sql & .edmx file it will be entity framework.